# What are the different logs under kafka data log dir

Tags: apache-kafka

I am trying to understand the kafka data logs. I can see the logs under the dir set in logs.dir as "Topicname_partitionnumber". However I would like to know what are the different logs captured under it. Below is the screenshot for a sample log.

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [why .index file exists in kafka-log directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19394669/why-index-file-exists-in-kafka-log-directory)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Kafka logs, each partition has a log.dir directory. Each partition is split into segments.

A segment is just a collection of messages. Instead of writing all messages into a single file, Kafka splits them into chunks of segments.

Whenever Kafka writes to a partition, it writes to an active segment. Each segment has defined size limit. When the segment size limit is reached, it closes the segment and opens a new one that becomes active. One partition can have one or more segment based on the configuration.

Each segment contains three files - **segment.log,segment.index and segment.timeindex**

There are three types of file for each Kafka topic partition:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka hadoop  10485760 Dec  3 23:57 00000000000000000000.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka hadoop 148814230 Oct 11 06:50 00000000000000000000.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka hadoop  10485756 Dec  3 23:57 00000000000000000000.timeindex
```

The `00000000000000000000` in front of log and index files is the name of the segments. It represents the offset of the first record written in that segment.  If there are 2 segments i.e. Segment 1 containing message offset 0,1 and Segment 2 containing message offset 2 and 3.

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka hadoop  10485760 Dec  3 23:57 00000000000000000000.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka hadoop 148814230 Oct 11 06:50 00000000000000000000.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka hadoop  10485756 Dec  3 23:57 00000000000000000000.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka hadoop  10485760 Dec  3 23:57 00000000000000000002.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka hadoop 148814230 Oct 11 06:50 00000000000000000002.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 kafka hadoop  10485756 Dec  3 23:57 00000000000000000002.timeindex
```

`.log` file stores the offset, the physical position of the message, timestamp along with the message content. While reading the messages from Kafka at a particular offset, it becomes an expensive task to find the offset in a huge log file.
That's where `.index` the file becomes useful. It stores the offsets and physical position of the messages in the log file.

[image]

`.timeindex` the file is based on the timestamp of messages.

Comment: Thanks. This makes it clear. Also i do not see message timestamp in .log file. Do we need to make any changes in the config file to get it recorded? We need to know the message in time in the partition.

Comment: timestamps are included in the messages for Kafka 0.10+ version. Which kafka version are you using?

Comment: 0.10.2.x is the kafka version

Comment: Here is a sample from one of the .log (data) file. I can see few extra characters/symbols but not the date. I tried opening it with notepad and notepad++. https://pastebin.com/hStyCW13

Answer (score 0):

The files without a suffix are the segment files, i.e. the files the data is actually written to, named by earliest contained message offset. The latest of those is the active segment, meaning the one that messages are currently appended to.

`.index` are corresponding mappings from offset to positions in the segment file. `.timeindex` are mappings from timestamp to offset.

Comment: The files without extensions are like that probably because of a Windows configuration option that hides the extension when it is linked to an application

Comment: Certainly not running Kafka on Windows :)

Comment: Check the screenshoot from OP, that is Windows Explorer. Kafka runs in Windows, also he could have copied the files with FTP.

Answer (score 0):

> Below is the screenshot for a sample log

You should add your `screenshot` and `sample log`, then we could give your expected and specific answer.

---

before that, only can give you some common knowledge:

eg: in my CentOS, for folder:

`/root/logs/kafka/kafka.log/storybook_add-0`

- `storybook_add`: is the **topic** name

  - in code, the real topic name is `storybook-add`

its contains:

```
[root@xxx storybook_add-0]# ll
total 8
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10485760 Aug 28 16:44 00000000000000000023.index
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      700 Aug 28 16:45 00000000000000000023.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 10485756 Aug 28 16:44 00000000000000000023.timeindex
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root        9 Aug 28 16:44 leader-epoch-checkpoint
```

- `00000000000000000023.log`: log file

  - store the real data = kafka message
- `00000000000000000023.index`: index file
- `00000000000000000023.timeindex`: timeindex file

->

- `00000000000000000023` called segment name

  - why is `23`?

    - in `00000000000000000023.log`, which stored first message's postion is 23

      - kafka previously has totally received `23` messages
- what the message data look like?

  - we can see through its content:

    - [image: cat segment log content]

---

For further basic concept and logic of kafka, recommend to read this article:

[A Practical Introduction to Kafka Storage Internals](https://medium.com/@durgaswaroop/a-practical-introduction-to-kafka-storage-internals-d5b544f6925f)